# Mysql Table referencing updating

Tags: mysql, copy, foreign-keys

I want to create 2 tables :

**Table error_ref**

```
err_code    - int      -  primary key auto increment
description - varchar  -  not null
```

**Table error**

```
id          - int      -  primary key auto increment
cs          - varchar  -  not null
ip          - varchar  -  not null
operator    - varchar  -  
source      - varchar  -
type        - varchar  - 
err_code    - int      - not null, references error_ref(err_code)
description - varchar  - THERE IS MY QUESTION
date_poll   - datetime -
```

I want the right error_ref(description) to be copied into error(description) when an err_code is set at error(description)

Should I make a SQL request each time I want it to be copied, or can I use some key properties to make it copy itself ?

Data in error_ref table will look like :

1. SSH connection failed
2. SNMP community not set
3. No response from ping

As I can have 500+ records in error table, I made this second table to easely modify any of my descriptions.

Comment: Use mysql TRIGGERS... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate the description in the `error` table. Use a `JOIN` to get the description from `error_ref` when you need it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Best practice is to use mysql relations to get data. But it's not from my repsonsibility. I already tried to defend this point of view...

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to add somewhere in my code a request like this one :

```
UPDATE error, error_ref
SET    error.description= error_ref.description
WHERE  error.err_code= error_ref.err_code
```